# Find two complex numbers such that...

Tags: complex-numbers

Find two complex numbers such that their sum is $\ 1+4i$ , their quotient is purely imaginary, and the real part of one of them is$\ -1 $.

I have tried to create two complex values called:
$\ z=-1+ci $ and $\ w=a+bi $ and computing its sum knowing the result. Therefore:
$\ -1+ci+a+bi=1+4i \rightarrow a=2 \land c+b=4 $.

---

Then, we know that $\ \frac{-1+ci}{2+bi}=xi $ being$\ x $ the variable that I included to form every purely imaginary complex number.
So, here is when i got stuck.

*Thank you in advance!*

***As has being answered, you just need to use the relation $\ c=4-b \land z=xiw $.
Solving for b will output a value of $\ b=2+\sqrt2 \lor b=2-\sqrt2 $ resulting in $\ c=2-\sqrt2 $ if $\ b=2+\sqrt2 $ and $\ c=2+\sqrt2 $ if $\ b=2-\sqrt2 $.***

Its just a matter of patience (so don't be like me, be patient).

Comment: if their quotient is purely imaginary then $w = ki z$

Answer (score 1):

Because $b+c=4$, we may as well write $c=4-b$.  Hence you have the purely imaginary
$$\frac{-1+(4-b)i}{2+bi}=\frac{-1+(4-b)i}{2+bi}\frac{2-bi}{2-bi}=\cdots$$

Comment: That's where i lose myself. Tried continuing and somehow arrived to: $\ \frac{-2+4b+b^2+(8+3b)i}{4+b} $ having a result of $ b= -2+-\sqrt(6)$ and its respective c. But when i try the division, the result is not purely imaginary.

Comment: 1. The denominator is $4+b^2$.  2. Forget about the denominator, for this to be purely imaginary you need $-2-4b+b^2=0$.

Comment: @vadim123 This is a minor point. As you stated, for the numerator to be purely imaginary means the real part needs to be $0$. However, the equation for that would be $-2 + 4b - b^2 = 0$ since $i(-bi) = b$.